# Highcharts - async drill-down in tree-map with thousands of items

Tags: highcharts

I wanted to know if it's possible to use an async drill down on treemap?

I have 7000 items that need to be drawn and it stuck while the treemap is creating.

So I think to create treemap by lazy loading. I didn't find any example of treemap with huge data (while the items are below 1000 it's not a problem like in the example of the large treemap).

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done exactly the same for any type of series.

**Example for treemap:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {

        this.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
          type: "treemap",
          layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
          data: [{
            name: 'A1',
            value: 11,
            drilldown: true
          }, {
            name: 'A2',
            value: 44
          }]
        });
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    type: "treemap",
    layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
    data: [{
      name: 'A',
      value: 6,
      drilldown: true
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      value: 2
    }]
  }]
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/knj7bqs5/